# React setState in componentDidMount not working

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Any idea why following setState for **popUpBurned** is not working?

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const { user } = this.props
    const { popUpBurned } = this.state
    const visits = user.visitsCounter

    if (visits === 6 && !popUpBurned) {

      this.setState({ popUpBurned: true })
      this._popupFeedbackVisits.show()
    }

  }
```

I need my `_popupFeedbackVisits` to trigger only once when the visit-number is 6, which works just fine. But when in the same visit, the user navigates to another page and comes back to dashboard, the popup triggers again (as the visits are still 6).

How can I make the popup to trigger once and only once? My though was to add that boolean, but it does not seems to work inside componentDidMount. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should use a store engine like [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)

Comment: can you show us where and how you set the visits counter please

Comment: what is the initial value of popUpBurned?

Comment: Agreed, Redux could be a good solution, or the new [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Also, consider storing the `popUpBurned` state in a parent that stays mounted.

Comment: visits-counter is set in the /login request and it works fine. The initial value of popUpBurned is false.

Comment: Well, I could use of course redux, but I thought it was to much of a weapon for such a little boolean state change... don´t you think? I will sure try it if no other solution appears. thanks all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work-around using sessionStorage solved the issue:

```
if (user.visitsCounter === 6 && !sessionStorage.getItem('popUpBurned')) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('popUpBurned', true)

      this._popupFeedbackVisits.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to store the `popUpBurned` somewhere else and pass it in as a prop to this component. It seems like from your post `user` is a global object and this should only ever happen once. Perhaps storing this on the user would be appropriate?

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const { user } = this.props
    const visits = user.visitsCounter
    const popUpBurned = user.popUpBurned

    if (visits === 6 && !popUpBurned) {

      this.setState({ popUpBurned: true })
      this._popupFeedbackVisits.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nitsew, thanks a lot. Yes, user is global and I will store popUpBurned there as I do with visitsCounter. But I would like to know... why is it so problematic settingState inside componentDidMount? I mean, is that the reason at all why it does not work? Just curious..

Comment: It's reading `props.user.popUpBurned` but still using `setState` to change it?

Comment: @CarlosdelRíoFrancés There is no issue calling `setState` in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, but in your use case it doesn't work because when the component unmounts, and re-mounts as you described, `this.state.popUpBurned` gets reset to the initial state value.

Component state is not persisted, which is why you need to store this outside of the sceop of the user.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If `popUpBurned` is not used in `render`, it probably doesn't need to be in `state` and you could make it a class property:

```
class ... extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        ...
        this.popUpBurned = false
    }

    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        const { user } = this.props
        const visits = user.visitsCounter

        if (visits === 6 && !this.popUpBurned) {
            this.popUpBurned = true
            this._popupFeedbackVisits.show()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi programmer. No, it is not in render. Can you explain me a bit more that about making a class property? thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot programmer, but I am trying that and it does not seem to work neither.. It remains false... But it was nice to learn and very worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the visit number in if statement, so that it does not trigger the related function again. Because in any refresh or coming back to the page will make componentDidMount work, and then it continues to popup.